# Why My Widget .accessoryRectangular doesn't appear on the HomeScreen, but on the list to select it is

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit

Here is how it looks like:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The following things are checked:

- provisioning profiles
- info plist
- available families
- bundle identifier is consistent

There is only diamond icon defined from the image assets, so there is no way to have memory issues

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "icon-diamond")!)
```

What am I missing?

I assume that if there is anything wrong it wouldn't appear even on the list to select.

I have restarted device a few times.